# MongoDB Aggregation Query Null fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

In collection of documents i have structure like this:

```
{
    'number': '0001',
    'name': 'user №',
    'sessions': [
        {
            'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'),
            'session_id': '7WGnQhFGgDgC2FDfGwbgEaLbPMMBofPFVrVh9Pn2quooAcgxZc',
            'actions': [
                {
                    'type': 'read',
                    'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T01:20:01'),
                },
                {
                    'type': 'read',
                    'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T01:21:13'),
                },
                {
                    'type': 'create',
                    'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T01:33:59'),
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to write an aggregation query that will display the last action of each user and each action type, and their sum, in this form:

```
    {
    'number': '0001',
    'actions': [
        {
            'type': 'create',
            'last': 'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T01:33:59'),
            'count': 1,
        },
        {
            'type': 'read',
            'last': 'created': ISODate('2020-01-01T01:21:13'),
            'count': 2,
        },
        {
            'type': 'update',
            'last': null,
            'count': 0,
        },
        {
            'type': 'delete',
            'last': null,
            'count': 0,
        },
    ]
}
```

So, I already wrote a request, but I do not know how to output the action with the count == 0, and how to format the output correctly:

```
[{$unwind: "$sessions"}, 
{$unwind: { path: "$sessions.actions" }}, 
{$group: {"_id": {"number": "$number",
            "type": "$sessions.actions.type"},
            "created": {"$push": "$sessions.actions.created"},
            "count": {"$sum": 1}}}, 
{$group: {"_id": {"number": "$_id.number"},
       "actions": {"$push": {"type": "$_id.type", 
       "last": {"$max": "$created"}, 
       "count": "$count"}}}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using mongodb server 4.2 or higher you can use set https://mongoplayground.net/p/21XH75s-usE

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$sessions"
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$sessions.actions"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "number": "$number",
        "type": "$sessions.actions.type"
      },
      "created": {
        "$push": "$sessions.actions.created"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "number": "$_id.number"
      },
      "actions": {
        "$push": {
          "type": "$_id.type",
          "last": {
            "$max": "$created"
          },
          "count": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "actions": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(actions) {try { var act = ['read', 'create', 'delete', 'update']; act.forEach((entry) => { if (actions.filter(e => e.type === entry).length < 1) { actions.push({ 'count': 0, type: entry, last: null }); }}) }catch (e) { } return actions}",
          "args": [
            "$actions"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

here we check if any action is missing if missing we add the default value